# Rails ActionMailer Sending Email to Nested Distribution Lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I can send an email to a distribution list with no problem, let's just say it's called `MY_DIST_LIST`.

So when I'm delivering an email with ActionMailer, I am saying to send it `to: MY_DIST_LIST@company.com`

That works great, however... if `MY_DIST_LIST` has another distribution list inside of it, we'll call it `OTHER_LIST`. Delivery to `OTHER_LIST` will fail since it doesn't have the `@company.com` appended.

**NOTE: I believe all of these distribution lists are created in Outlook**

What would be the right way to make that work?

Here are my SMTP settings:

```
# SMTP configuration settings
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "mymailaddress.com",
  port: SOME_PORT,
  domain: "mymail.domain.com",
}
```

If you'd like any further information, please let me know in the comments.